# Как правильно настроить в JACKSON DeserializationConfig для работы с Date

Tags: java, json, jackson

Как настроить Jackson `DeserializationConfig` так, что бы он не проставлял в поля объекта даты? Сейчас ситуация такая. Мне приходят `Date` через `GET`, и если какой–то из параметров пустой, то Jackson дисиреализует его в дату, которая сейчас.

Мне нужно, чтоб если  параметр с датой не заполнен, то он был NULL.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример даты, дающей неправильный результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас, наверное, где-то в самом бине поле инициализируется. Или версия Jackson старая.

```
public class Bean {

    public String name;
    public Date date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean [name=" + name + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }
}

String json0 = "{ \"name\": \"test\" }";
String json1 = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"date\": \"\" }";
String json2 = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"date\": \"null\" }";
String json3 = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"date\": \"2016-06-11\" }";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json0, Bean.class));
// Bean [name=test, date=null]
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, Bean.class));
// Bean [name=test, date=null]
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, Bean.class));
// Bean [name=test, date=null]
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json3, Bean.class));
// Bean [name=test, date=Sat Jun 11 00:00:00 TZ 2016]
```

Comment: Проблемма была не в jackson